# Problem with initial and ending frames when using a matplotib widget to scroll horizontally through a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matrix with many columns and wish to scroll horizontally through the corresponding heatmap. When the slider is set to its initial value, the heatmap of the entire matrix is shown. I only want the first ten columns to initially appear. When the slider equals its final value, a band of white space appears. My code thus far, which is based loosely upon an example shown at https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/23577/interactive-controls-with-matplotlib-widgets

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

M=np.random.rand(4,6000)
scroll_win_size=10. 
# the matrix has 6000 columns; I wish to view 10 at a time. I also want
#the graph to initially show only 10 columns when I run the script, and not all 6000. 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

plt.imshow(M,aspect='auto',cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()

num_samples=M.shape[1]

axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor='lightgoldenrodyellow')
spos = Slider(axpos, 'time', 0, num_samples-scroll_win_size,valinit=0,valstep=10)


def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.axis([pos,pos+scroll_win_size,0,3])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

I've included three images below: One when the slider value is zero, one when it reaches its maximum, and one in between.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use the update function to set the value of the axis to 5990 or less so that it ends at the maximum value of the slider.

```
def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    if val < 5990:
      ax.axis([pos,pos+scroll_win_size,0,3])
      fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helps with removing the white space in the second image above when the widget value reaches its maximum. However, when I run the script, it's still the case that the initial image is for the entire matrix, not just the first 10 columns (first image above). Not until I use the widget do I only 10 columns at a time. Any way you see to remedy this, or is it not really possible?

Comment: This could be done by initially setting the axis to the number you want to display. You can try this.`plt.imshow(M,aspect='auto',cmap='jet');ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 3]);plt.colorbar()`